# I want to keep a Webview in Shared Preferences

Tags: flutter, webview, sharedpreferences

When I open the app, I want to display the web pages I visited in the past as they are.
As a preliminary step, it takes time to implement Webview.

The screen will change from the setting screen to the view screen.
First, enter the URL you want to display in Webview on the setting screen.
When you press the connect button, the screen transitions to the view screen with the URL as a parameter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS7cU.png)

On the view screen, the page with this URL should be displayed, but it is a blank screen as shown in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtfG1.png)

From the text in the appbar, you can see that the parameter itself has been received.

The view.dart on the view screen is coded as follows.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'Widgets/drawer.dart';

class ViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/view';
  final String url;

  viewScreen({Key key, @required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ViewScreenState();
}

class ViewScreenState extends State<ViewScreen> {
  String _view = "message";

  void _load() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _view = pref.getString('url') ?? '';
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_view),
      ),
      drawer: DrawerScreen(),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: _view,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        javascriptChannels: Set.from([
          JavascriptChannel(
              name: "getData",
              onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage result) {
              }),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I wondered if it was necessary to set up the network, and I wrote https://twitter.com/home directly to the initialUrl (the part where the URL you want to display in Webview is set as a String), and the connection was established.

```
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'Widgets/drawer.dart';

class ViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/view';
  final String url;

 ViewScreen({Key key, @required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>ViewScreenState();
}

classViewScreenState extends State<ViewScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
     appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.url),
      ),
      drawer: _drawer(context),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: widget.url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        javascriptChannels: Set.from([
          JavascriptChannel(
              name: "getData",
              onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage result) {
              }),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrglR.png)

If you have any idea, I would appreciate it if you could point it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `FutureBuilder`, `widget` that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a `Future`. 
code snippet

```
  Future<String> _future;  

  Future<String> _load() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _view = pref.getString('url') ?? '';
    return Future.value(_view);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();   
    _future = _load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                ...
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return WebView(
                      initialUrl: _view,
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      javascriptChannels: Set.from([
                        JavascriptChannel(
                            name: "getData",
                            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage result) {}),
                      ]),
                    );
                  }
              }
            }));
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/view';
  final String url;

  ViewScreen({Key key, @required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ViewScreenState();
}

class ViewScreenState extends State<ViewScreen> {
  Future<String> _future;
  String _view = "message";

  Future<String> _load() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _view = pref.getString('url') ?? '';
    return Future.value(_view);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //_load();
    _future = _load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(_view),
        ),
        //drawer: DrawerScreen(),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return WebView(
                      initialUrl: _view,
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      javascriptChannels: Set.from([
                        JavascriptChannel(
                            name: "getData",
                            onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage result) {}),
                      ]),
                    );
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await pref.setString('url', 'https://twitter.com/home');
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ViewScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: Can I ask another question?
I want to be able to see Twitter when I open the app after turning off the power once. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the same approach I used to develop my Android example app: [Flutter Browser](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_browser_app).
It's a Web Browser (published on Google Play [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_browser) if you would take a look) that is developed using my [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin.

I'm using the [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package for state management and, when an event that triggers URL change occurs, such as `onLoadStart` or `onLoadStop`, I save the current WebView Tab URL using the [`shared_preferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin.

I have 2 main Models: the `BrowserModel` and the `WebViewModel`, where the first one contains all the general information/configuration of the Browser and each WebView Tab. Each WebView Tab has its own `WebViewModel` that represents the current state, such as URL, enabled/disabled configuration, etc.

Both `BrowserModel` and `WebViewModel` are converted into JSON format and saved using `shared_preferences` using the `save()` and `flush()` methods (both methods are defined in the `BrowserModel` class [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_browser_app/blob/master/lib/models/browser_model.dart)).

When the App is completely closed and re-opened again by the user, it will check if there is something to restore, and, if it is, it restores all the configuration and WebView Tabs the user left open through the `restore()` method (you can find it in the same `BrowserModel` class [here](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_browser_app/blob/master/lib/models/browser_model.dart)).